# Ruby - Executing tests in a random order with rake

Tags: ruby, random, testing, rake

How can I have the tests for my Rails app to be executed in a random order?
Is there a simple solution using rake?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: To ensure that there are no dependencies between tests?

Comment: Yes, the main point for us is to ensure that there are no dependencies between tests.

Comment: See also [Why does Test::Unit.test_order= not working as expected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185517/why-does-testunit-test-order-not-working-as-expected)

Answer (score 5):

Here you go, define this in `lib/tasks/tasks.rb`

```
namespace :test do 
  namespace :randomize do 
    desc "Randomize tests"
    Rake::TestTask.new(:all => "db:test:prepare") do |t|
      t.libs << "test"
      t.test_files = Rake::FileList[
        'test/unit/**/*_test.rb',
        'test/functional/**/*_test.rb', 
        'test/integration/**/*_test.rb' 
      ].shuffle
      t.verbose = true
    end
  end
end
```

Run: `rake test:randomize:all`

Keep in mind that within file tests will still be executed in the order they appear. I guess you could monkey patch test unit to allow for that.

Comment: Thanks Sam.

This does not work to me, and actually the solution you posted is the same one I came to: simply shuffle the array containing the list of test files to execute.

As a matter of fact, the order of test files you pass to the rake TestTask seems to be ignored, meaning that internally rake will sort this list alfabetically on the name of the file.
I verify this behavior executing the rake task with the TESTOPTS="-v" option, to monitor the actual test execution order.

Here are the versions I use:
Ruby: 1.8.6 - 114
RubyGems: 1.3.5
Rake: 0.8.7
Rails: 2.3.3

Do you have more ideas? 
Tx!

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to check out "ZenTest 3.9.0: now with more Evil" (can't do a direct link, use google's cache)

```
Added ability to set test execution order, defaults to :random. EVIL!
```

Comment: I played some time with ZenTest, but I never guess how to enable random order. I mean, the default execution order is fixed and remains the same across different test executions.