# Why does Test::Unit.test_order= not working as expected?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

There is the question [In Ruby, how to I control the order in which Test::Unit tests are run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772890/in-ruby-how-to-i-control-the-order-in-which-testunit-tests-are-run) and wanted to answer with a reference to `test_order = :defined`,

The [documentation for `Test::Unit::TestCase.test_order`](http://test-unit.rubyforge.org/test-unit/en/Test/Unit/TestCase.html#test_order=-class_method) says:

> Sets the current test order.
>
> Here are the available order:
>
> - :alphabetic 
>     Default. Tests are sorted in alphabetic order.
> - :random 
>     Tests are sorted in random order.
> - :defined 
>     Tests are sorted in defined order.

So I thought this would execute the tests in order of method definition:

```
gem 'test-unit'
require 'test/unit'
class Mytest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  test_order = :defined
  #~ test_order = :random
  #~ test_order = :alphabetic #default
  def test_b
    p :b
  end
  def test_a
    p :a
  end
  def test_c
    p :c
  end
end
```

But when I execute it (tested with test-unit 2.4.9 and 2.5), I get the alphabetic order:

```
Started
:a
.:b
.:c
.
```

What's the problem? Is there something missing in my code, is the documentation wrong or is there a bug?

Comment: I know it's obvious, but I'll point it out anyway: depending on the order in which tests are run most probably means that something's wrong.

Comment: @s.m. Yes I kno, I try to avoid it. But sometimes I prefer to get a predefined order, so my _more important_ tests are tested first. I could order my tests with method name, but then I rely on the alphabetical order.

Comment: I found this pull request in meantime: https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/pull/122 There is the expanation, why it is not part of MiniTest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I detected the solution, or better my fault:

```
gem 'test-unit'
require 'test/unit'
class Mytest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  self.test_order = :defined
  #~ self.test_order = :random
  #~ self.test_order = :alphabetic #default
  def test_b
    p :b
  end
  def test_a
    p :a
  end
  def test_c
    p :c
  end
end
```

The difference: I used `test_order = :defined` in my class. 
What happened: A local variable `test_order` was created.

With `self.test_order = :defined` the method `test_order=` is called.

Comment: My problem ended up being I am using an older version of TestCase that doesn't support test_order: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/TestCase.html Thank you though, at least it helped me conclude I was actually setting that var correctly and something else must be wrong (bounty awarded!)